# How to install a VSIX file to Visual Studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nunit

Im on a new C++ project and feeling hopelessly out of my depth as Ive not done C++ since Vis Studio 2005.  So a few questions coming.
The PC Im using to develop on is not connected to the internet.

I have Visual Studio 2013, Update 3 and I need Nunit on it.
I have been pointed to a file named: NunitVisualStudiotestAdaptor-2.0.0.vsix

How do I get it installed?

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/73675/how-do-i-install-a-vsix-file-in-visual-studio). Double clicking the vsix should work.

Comment: Yep it did.  Feel like a dork now.   :-S   Cheers!